# ERROR org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: error parsing conf mapred-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

```
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2924)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </name>; expected </nafme>.
 at [row,col,system-id]: [39,40,"file:/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:621)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:491)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:475)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.reportWrongEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3365)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3292)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2911)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$Parser.parseNext(Configuration.java:3320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$Parser.parse(Configuration.java:3114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3007)
        ... 14 more
2022-12-02 13:21:18,536 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </name>; expected </nafme>.
 at [row,col,system-id]: [39,40,"file:/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"]
2022-12-02 13:21:18,551 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at hadoop162/192.168.10.162
************************************************************/
2022-12-02 13:21:18,597 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: error parsing conf mapred-site.xml
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </name>; expected </nafme>.
 at [row,col,system-id]: [39,40,"file:/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:621)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:491)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:475)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.reportWrongEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3365)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3292)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2911)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$Parser.parseNext(Configuration.java:3320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$Parser.parse(Configuration.java:3114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3007)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2968)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2848)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1789)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
```

```
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/logs » xcall                                                               atguigu@hadoop162
========== hadoop162 =========
3642 Jps
========== hadoop163 =========
3047 NodeManager
2603 DataNode
2893 ResourceManager
3503 Jps
========== hadoop164 =========
1191 DataNode
1368 NodeManager
1597 Jps
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/logs »                                                                     atguigu@hadoop162
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ1TI.png)

there is an exception ,I can't start hadoop ,

```
022-12-02 13:21:18,597 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: error parsing conf mapred-site.xml
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </name>; expected </nafme>.
 at [row,col,system-id]: [39,40,"file:/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have mismatched XML tags.

`nafme` isn't a valid property tag